# How do I reduce my simple game to 18 lines of MATLab code

Tags: matlab

I have recently been tasked with reducing a simple game written in MATLab code to a maximum of 18 lines of code. This can be done through getting rid of redundancies but I am having trouble distinguishing them so far. My code currently runs to 24 lines.

The requirements for the game are as follows:

"In this exercise you are required to implement a simple two player counting game. The game starts by setting the count to 0. The two players should take alternative turns selecting between the numbers 1 and 2. In each turn the number the current player selects gets added to the count. The player who reaches a value 10 or larger wins the game. The program should check for input correctness. The image below has a sample run.

Note: You must make the program a maximum of 18 lines of code but you're not allowed to achieve this goal by putting multiple statements/commands on the same line."

One more thing: I have noticed that this part of my code...

```
if count >= 10
    disp('Player x wins!');
end
```

... is positioned improperly because even if player 1 wins and the game exclaims it to be so, Player 2 will still be asked to input a number. I'm not sure how to fix this either. Sorry! (I'm sure that changing this code somehow will help in reducing the grand line total down to 18.)

Please help me! I've been tearing my hair out for 3 hours!

Thank you!

```
clear
clc
count = 0;
while count < 10;
    oneOrTwo = input('Player 1\nEnter 1 or 2: '); % Player 1 choose
    while oneOrTwo ~= 1 && oneOrTwo ~= 2
        oneOrTwo = input('Incorrect input. Try again: ');
    end
    count = count + oneOrTwo;
    if count >= 10
        disp('Player 1 wins!');
    end
    oneOrTwo = input('Player 2\nEnter 1 or 2: '); % Player 2 choose
    while oneOrTwo ~= 1 && oneOrTwo ~= 2
        oneOrTwo = input('Incorrect input. Try again: ');
    end
    count = count + oneOrTwo;
    if count >= 10
        disp('Player 2 wins!');
    end
end % This currently ends at line 24
```

Comment: There are two blocks that have the same code but differ in current player. Have you tried defining a second function with this code and have the current player as a parameter? You could also drop the `clear` and `clc`.

Comment: @R.Schifini I have noticed this and unfortunately could not find a way to simplify it without messing up the code that depends on there being a while loop. I've been doing this for so long that I've become too tired to think up a proper solution.

Comment: @R.Schifini I actually didn't know you could create a function with a parameter in MATLab for a situation such as this. I am a novice programmer so I am still learning these things but that might just be the solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: If you introduce a new variable `playerNumber` and utilize [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), you can compress the `while`-loop body to just one value check loop and one win check condition.

Comment: Also, this line requirement is pretty strict (aside from being completely useless and non-instructive to me) as I got it down to 16 lines with my style rule of "one expression per line".

Comment: @TroyHaskin Yeah I know the requirements are silly but that's extra credit for you. Thank you for the advice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it down to 12 lines of code. Try this:

```
clc
count = 0;
player = 1;  % 0: player 1,  1: player 2
while count < 10;
    player = mod(player+1,2);
    oneOrTwo = input(['Count: ' num2str(count) '\nPlayer ' num2str(player+1) '\nEnter 1 or 2: ']);
    while oneOrTwo ~= 1 && oneOrTwo ~= 2
        oneOrTwo = input('Incorrect input. Try again: ');
    end
    count = count + oneOrTwo;
end
disp(['Player ' num2str(player+1) ' wins!']);
```

As you can see, the input process is compressed into one by using the `player` variable.

The winning condition was removed from inside the while, since once `count` exceeds 10 the loop ends. Then, the winner message is displayed.

Removed the `clear` instruction, since the two main variables are initialized at the start.

Also added the current `count` information when asking for the input.

Comment: You could add a `clc` after a correct input in order to have a clean screen for the next input or the winning message.

Comment: Wow! I haven't had time to implement any of your help yet or anyone else's but I am still amazed you managed to reduce the code to only 12 lines. Thank you so much for you help! (You have saved me so much time)

Comment: I must ask, how did you know how to implement the code: player = mod(player+1,2); as an effective turn counter?

Comment: If you want to cycle 1, 2, 3 and 4 what you do is use the modulo function `mod(a,b)`.  But `mod(n,4)` will return 0, 1, 2 and 3, so add 1 to everyone and you get the correct cycle.

Comment: Another way to alternate between 1 and 2 is using `(-1)^n`.  But this results in -1, 1, -1, 1, ... In this case do: `0.5 * (-1)^n + 1.5`

Comment: I really didn't there were so many ways to do that one process. Thank you for your help!